# Accessing java comment in array using reflection

Tags: java

Imagine there is an array variable like the following:

```
private static final String[] STRINGS = {
        // Put log lines to test here
        "a",
        // Jira ticket 1
        "b",
        // Jira ticket 2
        "c" 
};
```

Essentially I am building code that would go to this class and copy the STRINGS array. Would it possible to use reflection to get this STRINGS array with the nested comments? I don't think this is possible but I wanted to ask if there are different directions I could possibly take. The comments are useful to tracking changes and I am trying to use this as a way to keep that information.

Comment: Comments are not retained in compiled code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain things just disappear once compiled. Some generics, and all comments, just are not in that class file, and the source file is not there at runtime, so, the answer is simple: **impossible**.

There are some alternatives. For example, you could ship the source file (pack into the jar as you deploy it), and then parse the sources, but parsing java code is decidedly non-trivial, so I really don't recommend this route.

You can also put these comments in simple text files, and pack those in, that's a much better plan; you can use `MyClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("jira-ticket-assignments.txt")` to get an inputstream with this data, and that works as long as a file named `jira-ticket-assignments.txt` is in the exact same place `MyClassName.class` is (even in a jar file, not a problem).

It's that, or turn those comments into string literals instead:

```
private static final Map<String, String> STRINGS = Map.of(
    "a", "Jira ticket 1",
    "b", "Jira ticket 2",
    "c", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

As @rzwitserloot said above, certain things just disappear once compiled.
If you need to save some meta information in runtime, you can use annotations

```java
@Comment({
    "Put log lines to test here",
    "Jira ticket 1",
    "Jira ticket 2"})
private static final String[] STRINGS = {
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
};
```

For this need to create annotation:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Comment {
    String[] value();
}
```

And use in runtime:

```java
String[] comments = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredField("STRINGS").getAnnotation(Comment.class).value();
String firstElementComment = comments[0];
String secondElementComment = comments[1];
...
```